# how to running multiple graphs in multiple session without closing the session

Tags: python, session, tensorflow, object-detection

I would like to know how to run multiple graphs in multiple sessions, without closing all those sessions, I want all of them to work in parallel. How to do such thing?.

I am trying to run two similar graphs(same variables) in two sessions, but the output from them is getting compromised at some point and i am ending up with same output from both the sessions.

Comment: you can put many graphs into single tf.Graph object. Having multiple tf.Graph objects will make your life hard

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov The problem is both graphs have same variable names and both are pre-trained, so it will be difficult to rename them now. is there any way to create sub graphs(to put all in one single graph?

Comment: OK, if you are feeling adventurous, you could  use multiple sessions, and then track down all the places that use the wrong session. For instance, start_queue_runners will use default session, which could be the wrong session. Some pieces may need to be reimplemented to not rely on default session/default graph